# Massive (~10 sec) delay presenting keyboard first time with UIPopoverPresentationController displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, first-responder

I've built an iPad UI where I present a UIPopoverPresentationController from a custom UIViewController class. The UI consists of a UICollectionView with a number of cells, with each cell containing a button which will present the popover. The popover has it's sourceRect and sourceView properties set to the corresponding properties of that button; frame and superview respectively.

In this popover, there is a UITextField. When selecting this field for the first time after the custom UIViewController has been initialised and presented there is a very long delay (about 10 seconds) before the keyboard presents. There is no console output during the process. Subsequent keyboard presentations are smooth as silk. The delegate method, popoverPresentationController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView doesn't get called at all here, while other delegate methods fire as expected.

I've also tried using the older UIPopoverController in the same situation, yielding the same result.

It should be noted that the UI is landscape mode only, and the popover stretches to the bottom of the screen, so upon presentation, the popover resizes to accommodate the keyboard. I have a suspicion that it's this resizing that causes the delay, but I have nothing to actually base this on.

Has anybody else seen this behaviour and / or been able to overcome it somehow? It smells like a bug on Apple's side to me, since it only occurs the first time... but that doesn't really help me much.

All advice and ideas are appreciated.

Also, if anybody reading this with sufficient reputation could create the tag for the newer UIPopoverPresentationController, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In the unlikely event that anybody else runs into the same situation, the issue is the debugger.

The epic delay is only present when attached to the debugger. Run the same build without debugging, and everything runs smooth.

So I spent 1.5 days debugging a bug that wasn't there. I made a reproducer though, so I'll file a bug report with Apple.